# Fourier Transform without knowing equation of waveform

Tags: fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

I used python to convert the time-domain signal below into a frequency spectrum so that I can analyze the harmonics. To do this I used Python libraries, specifically numpy and called fft to get the spectrum. I now want to validate my results. I have x, y coordinates in Excel and the plot below. To validate, I know that I could try to compute the Fourier series myself. The problem that I'm having is that I can't actually figure out how to begin. I don't know the equation of the waveform below so I can't use the definition of the Fourier transform. Any ideas on how to do this manual validation (or any other suggestions on how to actually confirm whether my fft is correct) are extremely helpful.

---

Here's a plot of the time domain signal.

[image]

---

Here's a plot of the frequency domain spectrum.

[image]

Comment: This belongs on [https://dsp.stackexchange.com/](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: So you can't mathematically define either the time domain signal or the frequency domain signal?

Comment: @StevenClark, correct. I don't have the equation of the time domain signal. All I have is a csv file containing (x, y) points from -6 seconds to 6 seconds. I used the data in this file and called fft in some python code. I'm trying to figure out whether the results from my fourier spectrum are correct, but I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Then I think you need to link your csv file and perhaps also an image of your frequency spectrum results.

Comment: @StevenClark, I added the spectrum. Any suggestions on where I can upload and link the csv file?

Comment: That looks like it's "in the right ballpark", anyway: the time-domain signal looks like it's essentially a sum of just a few sinusoids... so the FT should be concentrated (Dirac delta-ish) at the corresponding frequencies, as the graph seems to indicate.

Comment: I believe I've seen others include a link to a drop-box file that anyone could access, but I'm not familiar with the procedure of setting up a drop-box file for global access.

Comment: @paulgarrett, thanks for the reply. The locations of largest amplitudes seem to be where I was expecting them, which gives me confidence in my implementation of the fft. Any ideas on how one could attempt to figure out what the amplitudes should be from the information I have? I've been trying to see if I could figure out the composition of the time-domain waveform (I agree that it look like it's just sine waves added together), but still haven't come up with the right combination.

Comment: There seem to be two primary frequencies in the time domain signal where the higher frequency is about 5x the lower frequency, and this seems somewhat consistent with the two large spikes in the frequency domain spectrum. The lower frequency seems to be about 60 Hz.

Comment: @StevenClark, that makes sense. The largest spike seen is at 60 Hz, with an amplitude slightly under 160. Do you know if there is any "simple" way to try to check the amplitudes?

Comment: @Bern, one way to "iterated-guess" a linear combination of sinusoids that approximates the graph is to just take a small collection of sinusoids, pick random-ish coefficients, graph the result, and keep tweaking them until you get a good approximation. The opposite approach is, as you've already done, numerically compute a FT ...

Comment: You could perhaps start off by plotting $160 \sin (2 \pi 60 x)+105 \sin(2 \pi 300 x)$ and then tweak it a bit to get a better match.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll give both of them a try and see where it takes me. I may comment again later if I run into interesting results/observations or if anything comes up. Always nice to be able to bounce ideas off people. Thanks again!